# pass memory stream to another class how to close it

Tags: c#

I have a separate class to create CSV file and add it to memory stream and a separate class to send the file(upload it to the cloud storage)
I did this separation because these are two different jobs, here is the class im creating memory stream:

```
public MemoryStream ExecuteUseCase(Myclass listOfStudents)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
        var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);           
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(listOfStudents.FileBody);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return memoryStream;              
        }
    }
```

as you can see I have removed the using from the block because if I add using there, they will close the stream and its not accessible in the other class, here is my second class:

```
     var memoryStream = this.convertToCsv.ExecuteUseCase(file);
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream, true);
            
            this approach works, but my only concern is the memoryStream disposal, how to close it? Or do I need even?
```

Comment: Yes, you want to close the memory stream. And for [seperation of concerns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/architectural-principles#separation-of-concerns) I'd argue that it would be wise to pass the stream from a class writing a file to another class respnosible for file uploads. Maybe pass it a file name / path where the source file is saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using in the class that uses it

```
using(var memoryStream = this.convertToCsv.ExecuteUseCase(file)){
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream, true);
}
```